# First or Last element in a List<> in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have a `List<string>` and I want to identify either the first or last element in the list so I can identify a different function to do with that item.

Eg.

```
foreach (string s in List)
{
    if (List.CurrentItem == (List.Count - 1))
    {
        string newString += s;
    }
    else
    {
        newString += s + ", ";
    }
}
```

How would I go about defining `List.CurrentItem`? Would a `for` loop be better in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the counter like this

```
         int counter = 0 ;
         foreach (string s in List)
         {
               if (counter == 0) // this is the first element
                {
                  string newString += s;
                }
               else if(counter == List.Count() - 1) // last item
                {
                newString += s + ", ";
                }else{
                 // in between
               }
                counter++;
       }
```

Answer (score 8):

Rather make use of [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.STRING.JOIN%29;k%28JOIN%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
>   collection, using the specified separator between each element or
>   member.

It is a lot simpler.

Something like

```
        string s = string.Join(", ", new List<string>
        {
            "Foo",
            "Bar"
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a linq based solution

Example :

```
var list = new List<String>();
list.Add("A");
list.Add("B");
list.Add("C");

String first = list.First();
String last = list.Last();
List<String> middle_elements = list.Skip(1).Take(list.Count - 2).ToList();
```

Comment: And what will happen if your list only has 1 element?

Comment: that is a very special case, pre checking must be done before using above example !

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
string newString = "";

foreach (string s in List)
{
  if( newString != "" )
    newString += ", " + s;
  else
    newString += s;
}
```